# 415 Unsupported Media Type asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

## Detail

I am trying to post a file from Postman to the endpoint I have created. but it gives me this error. I am not passing the header Content-Type in postman

> 415 Unsupported Media Type

## API

```
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> SendEmail([FromBody]Entity entity)
{
    try
    {

        return OK();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

## Class

```
public class Entity 
{
    public List<IFormFile> Files { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core form POST results in a HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44538772/asp-net-core-form-post-results-in-a-http-415-unsupported-media-type-response)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try using `[FromForm]` instead of `[FromBody]` for the method parameter if you're POSTing form data.

Answer (score 12):

In Postman, when creating a POST request, the default is "Text".  Change it to JSON.

Comment: I had success using [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) with a `headers: [['Content-Type', 'text/json'], ...]` option.

Answer (score 3):

In Postman, after ensuring that you're using raw and its in JSON format. Most especially when making GET request and you're not sending any data in the body of the request ensure that the body of the request is not empty. It must have an empty object: { }