# Error logging and handling in asp.net core mvc

Tags: asp.net-core

Let's say you made a bug in a code (like this for example [415 Unsupported Media Type asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49228906/415-unsupported-media-type-asp-net-core?noredirect=1&lq=1) ). And get 415 error from a web request. How do we find more information about the error? How can we log it?

Seems that `.UseExceptionHandler()` In Startup.cs does not catch it.

```csharp
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        // app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    app.UseStatusCodePages(async context =>
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        var statusCodeData = context.HttpContext.Features.Get<IStatusCodePagesFeature>();
            
        await context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(
            "Status code page, status code: " +
            context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode);
                
    });
    // app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

Comment: where is your code? this error is simple but a specific code is required to help diagnose the issue.

Comment: @Hopeless Do you mean that UseExceptionHandler should work for such kind of errors? I thought that it should be catched somewhere else

Comment: no I meant about fixing the error, but looks like you want to log it, never mind

Comment: this error should be logged just fine if you configure your logging correctly. So it would be helpful if you post your configuration code. What about the other errors? are they logged correctly? At least when debugging, I've seen many times this error being logged in the Output (debug) window just like other kinds of error.

Comment: I put the code. I don't see anything in output debug. The only way i was able to catch it in the code UseStatusCodePages lambda. I could add logging there. But it does not feel right, and i didn't find any more info besides 415 error code.

Comment: Regarding other errors. Exceptions that occur in controllers methods are displayed and logged in debug console just fine. But this one, error in model binding not.

Comment: how do you know that the exception/error is thrown? There might be some custom code (e.g: internally in some library you use) returning the result code of `415` but not actually throwing the exception. As far as I know there are some exceptions that could not be caught in filters but should still be globally logged fine. That's like exactly when you debugging. If it could not be logged to the Output window when debugging, there must be something really weird here. I think you can try reproducing it in an empty project, or add another testing (controller) action.

Comment: Good point. Thanks. I will try

Answer (score 0):

Try with Middleware. Create new class for Middleware:

```
public class ErrorLoggingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ErrorLoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            // Handle exception
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, exception, HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
    }


    private Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception, HttpStatusCode statusCode)
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)statusCode;

        // TO DO: Log exceptions : Azure AppInsights or File

        var message = "The requested resource was not found";

        var response = new 
        {
            ErrorDescription = $"{(int)statusCode} - {message}",
            ErrorCode = message
        };

        string responseStringContent;

        context.Response.ContentType = Application.Json;
        responseStringContent =
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(response, new JsonSerializerOptions() { PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase });

        return context.Response.WriteAsync(responseStringContent);
    }
}
```

Then configure this class in Startup:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory fac)
{
    ...
    app.UseMiddleware<ErrorLoggingMiddleware>();
    ...
}
```

Please find more details at:
https://blog.elmah.io/error-logging-middleware-in-aspnetcore/