# 415 Unsupported Media Type when uploading "multipart/form-data" to .Net Core 3.1 API but the file is accessible in middleware method

Tags: c#

After file is uploaded to the API method I get `415 Unsupported Media Type` error. But then I realized that I'm able to see in debug (in a middleware method) that the file is bound properly.

When I set a breakpoint in the controller method it is not hit, just the error `415 Unsupported Media Type` is returned to the client.

**Where should I look for what is responsible for failing the API request?**
How can I debug to understand the reason?

I already tried:

- Using `[FromForm]` attribute or removing it
- Adding `[Consumes("application/octet-stream", "multipart/form-data")]` to the controller or to the method
- Simplifying the controller method so that it even doesn't take any arguments and trying to watch HttpContext.Request in debug. But even then I got `415`

```cs
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    [Consumes("application/octet-stream", "multipart/form-data")]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public class MyController : ControllerBase {

        [HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
        public ActionResult Post()
        {
            return Ok(); // No breakpoint hit here
        }
    }
```

```cs
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseBrowserLink();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseResponseCompression();
            }

            ConfigureResponseCaching(app);
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseWebMarkupMin();
            app.UseAddHeaders();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                ...
            }
        }
```

**In middleware method uploaded file is accessible.**

[image]

```
POST /api/MyController HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:4200
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 55091
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Authorization: Bearer eyJ...
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryCVzYTIIxodXc0tF0
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: http://localhost:4200/example
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: .AspNetCore.Identity.Application=...
```

Comment: Did you try to use `FromForm`, as mentioned in this question [415 Unsupported Media Type asp.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49228906/415-unsupported-media-type-asp-net-core)?

Comment: Yes. I have seen the answer and used `FromForm` attribute

Comment: Remove all things relative file and try your post API is work or not I think the problem is not file

Comment: @Krystian, can you show the client's code?

Comment: @MichaelMao I removed and and problem still exists

Comment: @Karney. I'm not allowed to do so. But I keep trying to solve/investigate it, maybe the following days will bring some new ideas.

Comment: So the problem is not relative to file is your post try to do a simple post to make sure your post is correct

Comment: @Krystian, can you pass the file successfully through postman? If it could success, it may be the client's issue.

Comment: @MichaelMao Sorry, it was a misunderstanding, my bad. I removed everything NOT related to file from startup.cs so that large part of the application was not initialized and the problem still existed. I'll try what you suggested then. The suggestion is pretty basic but that's true, sometimes mistakes are very basic too.

Comment: Finally I realized there was a typo in the url, so the url was pointing to another existing method but the other method was not supposed to receive any file. That resulted in the same syptoms/errors which I had before I made the typo and before I used `FromForm`.
I appreciate your help, since you actually suggested that the code I posted should work correctly. This gave me more courage to look for the problem somewhere else then in the code posted.
What should I do now with the question? Should I remove it? What do you do usually in such a case?