# Why is [FromBody] needed for complex types in some cases?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I've started a fresh, empty ASP.NET Core 3.1 project. I've updated the `Startup.cs` to this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment()) app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
    }
}
```

and added some test logic:

```
public class SomeDto
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

[Route("/api/v1/foo")]
public class FooController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<SomeDto> Echo(SomeDto dto)
    {
        dto.Message += " echoooo...";
        return dto;
    }
}
```

I would now expect a call like this:

```
curl -d '{"message":"hi"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://localhost:44351/api/v1/foo -k
```

to return `{"message": "hi echoooo..."}`. Instead, the argument to the `Echo` method is always a `new` object without any `Message`.

If I attribute the argument with `[FromBody]` it does work.

All my searches lead to [the *similar but different* question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24625303/419956) which explains that `[FromBody]` is needed if the argument is a *simple* type, and *not* needed if it is a complex type. [Google searches](https://www.google.com/search?q=why+is+FromBody+needed) seem to lead to similar information.

But in my case the argument *is* a complex type (dto). So why does it not work without the attribute?

---

EDIT: Duplicate question properly let us know that you need `[ApiController]` above your `FooController` class to enable default behavior to read post body data.

Comment: Did this post answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50771647/confused-with-frombody-in-asp-net-core

Comment: It seems, that you are searching for old ASP.NET, for ASP.NET Core things were changed, `FromBody` is required for complex types. Have a look at this [article](https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/) for example, or check [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Comment: Yes @OrelEraki that's just about a duplicate. Didn't know `[ApiController]` was needed _in addition to_ inheriting from `ControllerBase` to get the behavior I was after. Thank you!