# .NET model binding not working in POST request with JsonProperty

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

I have a model like

```
public class DeleteMe
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public string LalaId { get; set; }

    public string Other { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to send a post request to an API action defined like

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Lala(DeleteMe requestPayload)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

with the post body being

```
{
    "id": "someID",
    "other": "someOther"
}
```

However, when I make this request, the `id` (LalaId) property isn't bound in the API action. If I send it as LalaId, then it works. But I want that property to be both sent to the client side and received from the client side as `id`.

I'm using .net core 3.1. I know that with core 3, they've switched from Newtonsoft to their own JSON implementation, but in my Startup.cs I have added

```
services
    .AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CustomJsonContractResolver();
        options.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new DateTimeToTicksJsonConverter());
        options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
    });
```

Which should force core to use Newtonsoft instead of System.Text.Json, right?

What is the issue here?

Thanks!

Comment: What's in CustomContractResolver? When I use those, I usually remove all the [JSONProperty] attributes from the model.

Comment: @clhereistian
public CustomJsonContractResolver()
 : base()
{
 this.NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy();
}

protected override JsonDictionaryContract CreateDictionaryContract(Type objectType)
{
 var contract = base.CreateDictionaryContract(objectType);

 var keyType = contract.DictionaryKeyType;

 if (keyType.IsEnum)
 {
  contract.DictionaryKeyResolver =
   key => ((int)Enum.Parse(keyType, key)).ToString();
 }

 return contract;
}

Comment: @clhereistian I use it for conversion of enum keys in dictionaries

Comment: Is your startup code and your endpoint in the same assembly? In other words, is it possible you are referencing two different Newtonsoft.Json.dll's?

Comment: Do you need `[FromBody]` for `DeleteMe requestPayload`?  See e.g. [Confused with FromBody in ASP.NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58156463).

Comment: I teseted with your codes and it works well,have you missed any codes related or  installed wrong package?

Comment: @clhereistian all one assembly

Comment: @dbc I think FromBody is only needed when you want to change the default behavior, which is that primitive vars like string come from the URL, and objects come from the body.