# Receiving unsupported media type while sending form data

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core

I know that similar question being asked earlier, though I could not just able to find the answer I am looking for. I have a fairly simple `post` method.

```
public class PeopleModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
[HttpPost("Add")] // api/people/add
public IActionResult AddPeople([FromBody] PeopleModel people)
{
     return Created("something/Id", people);
}
```

Now I am making my calls from Postman.

> At Header: `Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
>
> And at `Form-Data` I send
>
> `FirstName=Bruce LastName=Wayne`

Unfortunately I am receiving `415 Unsupported Media Type`

I did not understand what mistake I have made. Or I should not send as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Have you tried this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44538773 ? By the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#customize-model-binding-behavior-with-attributes), the right way to do it is using `FromForm` and not `FromBody`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core form POST results in a HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44538772/asp-net-core-form-post-results-in-a-http-415-unsupported-media-type-response)

Comment: `FromBody` means you're going to accept an object notation format such as `application/json`, `application/xml`. etc. The `x-www-form-urleconded` content type is not supported. For that you'd need `FromForm`, which then will not support `application/json`, etc. If you're trying to create one action that can handle both, you can not. You must have separate actions.