# why does Unsupported Media type in Asp.net core api with React?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, axios

It's been a day now trying to resolve the unsupported media type issue now but I am unable to figure it out. I am trying to send a file and text to post but I am not successful yet.

The error I am seeing on the console: status

```
: 
415
title
: 
"Unsupported Media Type"
traceId
: 
"00-ef4252366cffac045c2b77680ce7cba1-649e6d2199f4b4d3-00"
type
: 
"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13"
```

I looked at these [ASP.NET Core form POST results in a HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44538772/asp-net-core-form-post-results-in-a-http-415-unsupported-media-type-response) but not solved the 415 issue yet.

MyViewModel:

```
using Duende.IdentityServer.Models;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace OnlineSoccerShopping.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class ProductViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(0, 100000)]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Range(1, int.MaxValue)]
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public IFormFile Image { get; set; }
    }

}
```

my product controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<ProductViewModel>> PostProduct([FromForm] IFormFile file, ProductViewModel product)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (file == null)
        {
            return BadRequest("File is required.");
        }

        if (product == null)
        {
            return BadRequest("no data");
        }

        Product ob = new Product();


        if (file != null)
        {
            ob.Name = product.Name;
            ob.Description = product.Description;
            ob.Price = product.Price;
            ob.CategoryId = product.CategoryId;
            ob.ImageUrlName = await _azureStorage.UploadFileAsync(file);
        }

        _context.Products.Add(ob);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Get));
    }
```

Axios:

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("Name", product.Name);
    formData.append("Description", product.Description);
    formData.append("Price", product.Price);
    formData.append("CategoryId", product.CategoryId);
    formData.append("ImageUrl", product.ImageUrl);
    console.log("Product:", product);
    axios
      .post("https://localhost:7217/api/product", formData, {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
      })
      .then((res) => {
        setIsSuccess(true);
        setTimeout(() => {
          setIsSuccess(false);
          navigate("/");
        }, 5000);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        console.log("Error response data:", err.response.data);
      });
  };
```

useState:

I used useState to store the filling out inputs flied in the html form.

```
const [product, setProduct] = useState({
    Name: "",
    Description: "",
    Price: 0,
    ImageUrl: null,
    CategoryId: 0,
  });
```

Comment: Hi @TulaMagar, do you use the web api controller? If so, what if you add the `[FromForm]` attribute before the `ProductViewModel product`?

Comment: @Rena, I was trying to get a file but I am able to resolve the issue using `FromForm ProductViewModel product`